# OnMouseOver and instantly disappearing objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a OnMouseOver script that will activate a guipanel (using it as a popup tooltip) on specific objects. When clicked, those objects will disappear instantly (destroyed since single use uniques) - but the guipanel stays active since there's no OnMouseExit. I can't really afford to put a BoxCollider on the background as it will mess with a lot of my other BoxCollider triggers - is there any way around this, or a better way to do what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Script:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (gameObject.tag == "Target")
    {
        InfoReturned = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<InfoFill>().InfoPanel();
        PopUpInfoBoxes[0].text = InfoReturned[0];
        PopUpInfoBoxes[1].text = InfoReturned[1];
        PopUpInfoBoxes[2].text = InfoReturned[2];
        PopUpInfoBoxes[3].text = InfoReturned[3];

        PopUpPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
void OnMouseExit()
{
    PopUpPanel.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which destorys the instances on click on mouse button. Probably there you can set the PopupPanel to inactive

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: It's in a completely different script file and is pretty much just a simple DestroyObject (MySpriteGroup);

Comment: "I can't really afford to put a BoxCollider..." Have you looked into Physics Layers at all? You can give that newest collider a layer that removes that issue. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: I have actually. The unfortunate part of this is I didn't think this through really well...so none of the (currently working) code has checks for layers; they are all simple collision checks. I would have to rework everything to put that in, and I'm absolutely convinced I'll mess something up along the way. Doing it this way would be my last resort.

Comment: this procedure is very messy. For you to be able to continue, just have a static boolean so if(static variable boolean) Gui ToolTip. Or whatever you're trying to disable.